# Display vector layers after changing symbology using pyQGIS and the north symbol is not displaying

Tags: pyqgis

I am beginner in python, After doing labeling to one layer i could see it both in interface and output map but when i do it for the other 2 layers it is not exported to map but can be seen in interface.

How can I modify the code?

I did this coding with pyQGIS cookbook.

```
from qgis.core import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
import os
import glob
from datetime import datetime
from qgis.gui import *
import subprocess
shp_file = "D:\Shp\karad_contours.shp"
study_area = "D:\Shp\karad_study_area.shp"
benchmarks = "D:\Shp\karad_benchmarks.shp"
tiff_file = "D:\Autocad-Karad\karad_transparent_mosaic_group1.tif"
qgisApp = QgsApplication([], True)
qgisApp.setPrefixPath('C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis', True)
qgisApp.initQgis()
tiff = QgsRasterLayer(tiff_file)    
contours = QgsVectorLayer(shp_file, 'Karad contours', 'ogr')
studyarea = QgsVectorLayer(study_area, 'Karad study area', 'ogr')
bench_marks = QgsVectorLayer(benchmarks, 'benchmarks', 'ogr')
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(tiff)
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(contours)
layer1 = iface.activeLayer()
layer1.setCustomProperty("labeling", "pal")
layer1.setCustomProperty("labeling/enabled", "true")
layer1.setCustomProperty("labeling/fontFamily", "Arial")
layer1.setCustomProperty("labeling/fontSize", "10") 
layer1.setCustomProperty("labeling/fieldName", "elevation")
layer1.setCustomProperty("labeling/placement", "2") 
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(studyarea)
layer2 = iface.activeLayer()
myRenderer  = layer2.rendererV2()
layer2.setCustomProperty("labeling/isExpression", True)
mySymbol1 = QgsFillSymbolV2.createSimple({'color':'0,0,0,0','color_border':'#000000','width_border':'1'})
myRenderer.setSymbol(mySymbol1)
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(bench_marks)
layer3 = iface.activeLayer()
layer3.setCustomProperty("labeling", "pal")
layer3.setCustomProperty("labeling/enabled", "true")
layer3.setCustomProperty("labeling/fontFamily", "Arial")
layer3.setCustomProperty("labeling/fontSize", "10") 
layer3.setCustomProperty("labeling/fieldName", "name")
layer3.setCustomProperty("labeling/placement", "2") 
iface.mapCanvas().refresh()     
canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
layers = [QgsMapCanvasLayer(contours), QgsMapCanvasLayer(tiff)]
canvas.setLayerSet(layers)
canvas.zoomToFullExtent()
e = canvas.extent()
e = contours.extent()
e = tiff.extent()
mapSettings = canvas.mapSettings()
c = QgsComposition(mapSettings)
c.setPlotStyle(QgsComposition.Print)
x, y = 10, 10
w, h = c.paperWidth() - 20, c.paperHeight() - 20
mapSettings.setOutputSize(QSize(w, h))
composerMap = QgsComposerMap(c, x, y, w, h)
composerMap.moveContent(0, 0)
composerMap.setPreviewMode(1)
composerMap.grid().setStyle(3)
composerMap.grid().setFrameStyle(3)
composerMap.grid().setIntervalX(100)
composerMap.grid().setIntervalY(100)
composerMap.setShowGridAnnotation(True)
composerMap.grid().setAnnotationPrecision(2)
composerMap.grid().setAnnotationDirection(1, 0)
composerMap.grid().setAnnotationDirection(1, 1)
composerMap.grid().setEnabled(True)
composerMap.setFrameEnabled(True)
c.addItem(composerMap)
composerLabel = QgsComposerLabel(c)
composerLabel.setText("Benchmark Reference Image")
composerLabel.setItemPosition(180, 10)
composerLabel.setFont(QFont("Times New Roman",24, QFont.Bold))
composerLabel.adjustSizeToText()
c.addItem(composerLabel)
legend = QgsComposerLegend(c)
legend.setItemPosition(10.5, 160)
legend.modelV2().index(0, 0).data()
legend.setAutoUpdateModel(False)
c.addItem(legend)
scaleBar = QgsComposerScaleBar(c)
scaleBar.setStyle('Line Ticks Up')  # optionally modify the style
scaleBar.setComposerMap(composerMap)
scaleBar.applyDefaultSize()
scaleBar.setItemPosition(221, 187)
scaleBar.setNumSegmentsLeft(0)
scaleBar.setNumSegments(2)
c.addItem(scaleBar)
northarrowIcon = QgsComposerPicture(c)
northarrowIcon.setPos(QPointF(20,20))
northarrowIcon.setSceneRect(QRectF(255, 20, 20, 20))
northarrowIcon.setPictureFile("C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\north-arrow-orienteering-md.svg")
c.addItem(northarrowIcon)

# Save the map as png image
dpi = c.printResolution()
dpmm = dpi / 25.4
width = int(dpmm * c.paperWidth())
height = int(dpmm * c.paperHeight())
# create output image and initialize it
image = QImage(QSize(width, height), QImage.Format_ARGB32)
image.setDotsPerMeterX(dpmm * 1000)
image.setDotsPerMeterY(dpmm * 1000)
color = QColor(255, 255, 255)
image.fill(color.rgb())
# render the composition
imagePainter = QPainter(image)
sourceArea = QRectF(0, 0, c.paperWidth(), c.paperHeight())
targetArea = QRectF(0, 0, width, height)
c.render(imagePainter, targetArea, sourceArea)
imagePainter.end()
out_img = "D:\TCE\Output\out.png"
image.save(out_img, "png")
print out_img

# Save the map as pdf image
printer = QPrinter()
printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter.PdfFormat)
printer.setOutputFileName("D:\TCE\Output\out.pdf")
printer.setPaperSize(QSizeF(c.paperWidth(), c.paperHeight()), QPrinter.Millimeter)
printer.setFullPage(True)
printer.setColorMode(QPrinter.Color)
printer.setResolution(c.printResolution())
pdfPainter = QPainter(printer)
paperRectMM = printer.pageRect(QPrinter.Millimeter)
paperRectPixel = printer.pageRect(QPrinter.DevicePixel)
c.render(pdfPainter, paperRectPixel, paperRectMM)
pdfPainter.end()
print "pdf output"
```

Answer (score 1):

In the middle of your code, you have

```
layers = [QgsMapCanvasLayer(contours), QgsMapCanvasLayer(tiff)]
canvas.setLayerSet(layers)
```

You would need to expand this list with the other layers you want in the canvas.